# Why isn't my php form passing the data

Tags: php, html, forms, post

here is my code. I am not sure why after i input the first and last name the second page does not show the proper text.. The form is suppose to take in first name and last name into a text box.. Then on the next page when person submits it should validate that the proper type of data was input, and then print out text if it was not, or print out text if it was successful.

```
<body>
    <h2 style="text-align:center">Scholarship Form</h2>
    <form name="scholarship" action="process_Scholarship.php" method="post">
        <p>First Name:
            <input type="text" name="fName" />
        </p>
        <p>Last Name:
            <input type="text" name="lName" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="reset" value="Clear Form" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send Form" />
    </form>
```

my second form

```
<body>
<?php
    $firstName = validateInput($_POST['fName'],"First name");
    $lastName = validateInput($_POST['lName'],"Last name");

    if ($errorCount>0)
        echo <br>"Please use the \"Back\" button to re-enter the data.<br />\n";
    else
        echo "Thank you for fi lling out the scholarship form, " . $firstName . " " . $lastName . ".";

    function displayRequired($fieldName)
    {
        echo "The field \"$fieldName\" is required.<br />n";
    }

    function validateInput($data, $fieldName)
    {
        global $errorCount;

        if (empty($data))
        {
            displayRequired($fieldName);
            ++$errorCount;
            $retval = "";
        } 
        else 
        {
            $retval = trim($data);
            $retval = stripslashes($retval);
        }

        return($retval);
    }
    $errorCount = 0;
?>
</body>
```

Comment: Is your php code inside `process_Scholarship.php`? if so, then put `var_dump($_POST)` to see what is being submitted and whats no.

Comment: Some of your HTML escaped your `echo` delimiters (line 8)

Comment: From what it sounds like is that you need to pass page1 data to page 2 (usually done through hidden fields) for page 2 to validate and finalize the submit.

Comment: `echo <br>"Please use the \"Back\" button to re-enter the data.<br />\n";` -- notice the `<br>`? It should be wrapped inside the double-quotes.

Comment: echo <br>"Please use..." should be echo "<br>Please use...."

Comment: where are you defining $fieldName?